# How to upload files logged in as a user to the app creator's drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Hi all App Maker Gurus,

I am trying to create an app using Google App Maker that when published, allows a user to upload files to the app creator's google drive. For example, User A creates this app and shares it with User B, giving User B permission to use the app. User B uploads a file via Google Drive picker, and the file is saved onto User A's Google Drive. Does Google App Maker have the ability to configure a "centralized" drive where users with access to the app can all upload files there?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49677679/454137 - is it something you are looking for?... or maybe it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494893/454137

Comment: yes, the second link is very helpful. It is what I am trying to do, but I am getting this error after I click "upload" my file: All your files failed to upload. Please retry or remove the failed files. You may also add new files. Below the file name in the select a file window, it says "Server rejected." Do you know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: @Eric please include what you have attempted and the error you are getting in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just figured out the problem. I had a wrong team drive folder id. @moondaisy