# AppMaker and picker widget - uploading to a specific folder

Tags: upload, directory, picker, google-app-maker

I'm trying to have a button to allow users to upload a file, into a specific folder. I tried to follow other advise, and add this hook to

onPickerInit:

```
var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView()
uploadView.setParent('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // test folder

pickerBuilder.addView(uploadView);
```

I've set the MULTISELECT_ENABLED feature (without it, the destination folder is not respected), and I *can* in fact now upload the files where they belong. Yay!

HOWEVER: The picker widget now has *two* upload tabs. The first one just does the regular upload into the drive main folder, the second tab does the right thing. My guess is that appmaker contstructs the first upload tab behind the curtains and there is no feature to disable this.

This is obviously fairly quirky and hardly usable. My questions are:

1) are there (possibly undocumented) API calls in the pickerbuilder to remove the original upload view?

2) Is it possible to respect the destination folder even is the MULTISELECT feature is off ?

Many thanks in advance for any pragmatic solutions!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 07/28/2020**

Due to the constant changes in drive picker, this code aims for a more permanent solution:

```
var folderId = "10fYS3l32R6gk79POOSS8X_Vbsz7vqzRWX"; //the desired folder id
var prps = [];
for(var prop in pickerBuilder){
  var value = pickerBuilder[prop];
  if(!!value){
    if(typeof(value)==="object"){
      var proto = value.__proto__; //jshint ignore: line
      if(!!proto["addLabel"] && !!proto["addView"]){
        prps.push(prop);
        for(var key in value){
          var target = value[key];
          var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(target);
          if(type === "[object Array]"){
            prps.push(key);
            for(var key in target[0]){
              var value = target[0][key];
              if(typeof(value)==="object"){
                prps.push(key);
              }
            }
            for(var key in target[0]){
              var value = target[0][key];
              if(typeof(value)==="string") {
                prps.push(key);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}    
var views = pickerBuilder[prps[0]][prps[1]];
for(var i=0; i<views.length; i++){
  var view = views[i];
  if(view[prps[3]] === "upload"){
    view[prps[2]].parent = folderId;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 06/29/2020**

There has been another change in the Drive picker API. To make this work please change what you have to:

```
var folderId = "10fYS3l32R6gk79POOSS8X_Vbsz7vqzRWX"; //the desired folder id
pickerBuilder.rw.kf["0"].Ta.parent = folderId;
```

---

**EDIT 05/26/2020**

There has been another change in the Drive picker API. To make this work please change what you have to:

```
var folderId = "10fYS3l32R6gk79POOSS8X_Vbsz7vqzRWX"; //the desired folder id
pickerBuilder.xw.jf["0"].Ta.parent = folderId;
```

---

**EDIT 02/17/2020**

There has been a change in the Drive picker API. To make this work please change what you have to:

```
var folderId = "10fYS3l32R6gk79POOSS8X_Vbsz7vqzRWX"; //the desired folder id
pickerBuilder.mw.$e["0"].Ra.parent = folderId;
```

---

To answer your questions directly:

1.) YES 
2.) YES

Now, let's dig a little bit into what's happening under the hood. You are right:

> My guess is that appmaker contstructs the first upload tab behind the curtains and there is no feature to disable this.

However, we can manipulate the object. So instead of creating a new picker view, let's simply configure the default one to upload the files to the folder you want. We can achieve that by doing the following:

1.) After you insert a Drive Picker into your UI, make sure the **Drive Picker Properties** are all empty:
[image]

2.) Next, go to the event handlers and click on the **onPickerInit** event handler. Type in this code:

```
var folderId = "10fYS3l32R6gk79POOSS8X_Vbsz7vqzRWX"; //the desired folder id
pickerBuilder.SW.Vq["0"].mc.parent = folderId;
```

[image]

In summary, I've come to the conclusion that the property **SW** contains the array of drive views, which are saved under the property **Vq**. **Vq["0"]** is the first view in the array of views and the **mc** property contains the features; hence **parent = folderId**.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Out of curiosity, how did you inspect the pickerBuilder object or locate the code for analysis ?

Comment: To answer my own question, I just stringified the picker object to console and got something like

    {"Mda":"https://docs.google.com/picker","SW":{"Vq":[{"El":"upload","mc": 
    {"query":"docs","parent":"XXXXX"}}],"mc":{}},"wi":{},"Wba":[]}